# Are there computerized ontologies for Relativity and (Experimental) Physics? How to contribute?

Tags: experimental-physics, soft-question, education, relativity

As machines and automation can generally assist humanity in physical activities, and even exceed mere human capabilities, so, increasingly, also in tasks of [reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_reasoning). A basic component of the latter type of machines is an [ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) for defining some particular domain of discourse.

**My Questions**, relating to my specific domain of interest and expertise:

Are there any automated/computerized ontologies publicly available for the discourse domain of experimental physics (in general) and the thought-experimental foundations of the theory of relativity (in particular); providing (therefore) especially the notions of

- distinct identifiable "participants", and
- "coincidence" (such as encounters between two or more recognizable material participants) vs. "non-coincidence"

?

Are there any (public) opportunities to contribute to such ontologies and/or to them being established in the first place?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131076/44126

Comment: @rob: "_Related: [ [PSE/q/131076 {etc.}: Lexical/ontological/semantic knowledge base for physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131076/)...]_" -- Wow!, that's really sort of related. (Never underestimate a sufficiently diverse bunch of PhysSE contributors ... &). (Well, that guy who (elsewhere) first posted $$\frac{11.86~\text{a}}{2} =\! \approx \!= 5.9~\text{a}$$ had beat me to the punch, too ...)

Comment: It stuck out at me because it's the only other question I've seen here about ontology. If you find several you might [create a tag](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to group them together.

Comment: @rob: "_It stuck out at me because it's the only other question I've seen here about o._" -- In the strictest sense of "[Ontology (information science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29)", apparently. I did [the obvious search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=ontology) admittedly only soon after your "standard comment". (I claim and hope this doesn't make this question of mine "duplicate".) "_If you find several you might create a tag [...]._" -- How many "_several_"?? (I've created tags even on, at first, singular topics; just so I could spell it out.)

Comment: Tag to your heart's content. PS, no need to quote comment repies.